# IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 Intentions Tweaking (Insertion)

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

As I am looking for ways to speed development and usage with IDEA, I am using Intentions (I.e: Alt+Enter by default Keymapping) to auto-insert things like decelerations, constructors, and all that jazz, trying to keep myself well clear of using the mouse when I can.

One thing that does irritate me is with creating constants, fields, and parameters. After generating them, the IDE jumps to the position they are declared, and prompts for name and type. Usually this results in a double-hit of the enter key, however, leaves the cursor at there. Is there a way to jump back to the usage after declaring it through this feature?
Cheers.

Comment: What about Alt+Left to jump back? I know its not automatic, but it saves you some mouse clicks...

Comment: Under default keybindings, this simply jumps the tab selection to the left. Looks like I might have to rough it and use the mouse.

Comment: Apologies! It's Ctrl+Alt+Left

Comment: Cheers, works well enough. I was hoping "Last Edit Location" With `Ctrl+Shift+Backspace` would do what I wanted, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a field `foo`, you can type foo and then immediately use the quick fix intention to create a field foo. Now you can type <kbd>Alt +F7</kbd> ("Find Usages"). This will take you to the usage you just typed (since it is the only one). This assumes you have the "Skip results tab with one usage" option set in "Find Usages Settings (*Edit > Find > Find Usages Settings* or <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F7</kbd>). If you do not have that setting configured, the result will open in the *Find* tool window with the usage highlighted. You can then type <kbd>F4</kbd> (jump to source).

Comment: Will give this a shot when I'm back at the desk. Sounds logical, however, if I am using the same field name in different classes, whether in a super/subclass, or within another class of private scope, would it jump there? Is there a way to confine it to simply the current class?
Thanks for the response too. Keen to check this out.

Comment: As it does *not* do a seacrh forthe String *variableName* but rather the actual field itself, it would not jump to fields with the same name in different classes. However, you could use <kbd>Ctrl+F7</kbd> which is "Find useage in (current) File".

Comment: Should have known IntelliJ would search for linkage rather than literarily. Thanks